# Wrong tax calculation on donation pages

Tags: financial-accounts, taxes

When you have two items with tax, the total tax amount is calculated for the last item only. Has anyone faced this issue? Is there any configuration I am missing?

[image]

Comment: This looks like core bug, do you have any extension enabled related to contribution or tax?

Comment: Only GDPR extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is core a bug and could replicate on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/

Have submitted a [fix](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/18284) for this, can you try the [patch](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/18284.patch) and post your comment on the PR to speedup the merge process?

Comment: Wicked!! thanks for fixing the issue. The patch fixed the problem. Do you have idea if it will be available in next release? Its asking me to login to comment my test on fix, sorry i dont account on github.