# Sales Tax not added to total when memberships include donations that are separate transactions

Tags: civicontribute, civimember

We are having a problem with sales tax calculations when letting the user add an optional donation to a membership purchase or renewal. We need to separate the membership and donation into two transactions (selecting "Separate Membership Payment" on the membership tab of the contribution page) so that the the charitable donation receipt will be generated.  If we don't separate the payment, the sales tax is computed properly -- but then we can't generate a charitable donation receipt.

When we separate the transactions, the sales tax is not added to the membership purchase, but it does appear on the receipt but is not added or charged.

On the contribution page:

- Financial type is set to Donation - that type will generate a charity receipt, but no sales tax
- "Contribution Amount section enabled" is selected to let the user enter a donation with membership, with "allow other amounts" selected so that they can enter what they want
- "Separate Membership Payment" is selected, as described above

For example, if we select a $90 membership that needs $11.70 sales tax with an $100 extra donation:

Receipt 1 (for membership), shows sales tax but it is not added to the total:

[image: Total is not correct]

Receipt 2 (for donation) shows no sales tax and is correct:

[image: Tax is not charged - correct]

I have tried the [patch](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/37533/wrong-tax-calculation-on-donation-pages) but that didn't make a difference.

I am using WordPress 5.5.1 and CiviCRM 5.29.1 with CiviMember and CDN Tax Receipts extension.

Answer (score 0):

Looks a bug - can you log an issue in gitlab - https://lab.civicrm.org/groups/dev/-/boards

Comment: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/financial/-/issues/154